# Is it mandatory to for a blood pressure patient to take medicines throughout the life span?

Tags: diet, medications

I have blood pressure and I want to get rid of medicines.I developed High BP about 4 years ago. Can I prefer to cure it from natural diet that includes natural diet from Spinach, Apple, Carrot and Cucumber on a daily basis. 
Am I right in my approach? Seeking for professional health advice. Thank you

Comment: You should ask your doctor or other qualified healthcare professional about this.

Comment: Some people do reduce their blood pressure through lifestyle modifications, but we don't offer medical advice here. It's considered off topic.

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE.  Things work differently here.  If you are uncertain why we cannot give medical advice here, please see https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor

Answer (score 3):

If you would prefer to not take medication for high blood pressure, then your doctor can assist with that as well.  They do not have to only write you a prescription.  If you are willing to meet with a nutritionist, that is a great start, then adding in cardio workouts and perhaps something for stress reduction, which can be anything from yoga to painting to walks in nature, whatever works for you, even meditation is great for many.  You should not start doing these things without monitoring your blood pressure ever though.  If you are seeking to make any major lifestyle changes while medicated, your doctor needs to be involved.  If you stay on the medication and manage to decrease your blood pressure, then you will be over-medicated.  If instead you do not decrease it the way you hoped, but reduce your medication, you are left at risk for stroke or other issues from improperly controlled high blood pressure.  So yes, there are people who come off the medications, with a doctors guidance and monitoring, but it is only safe to do so with that help in place.  I am all for doing the things you need to get healthy, but no one needs to die on the way to getting healthy.

http://jasn.asnjournals.org/content/14/suppl_2/S99.full